# Why isn't my virtualenv opening up in visual studio code?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm working with Django right now and when I installed it through the command prompt I made a virtualenv called test, now I went into vs code and I am trying to open it up by saying workon test but it's not going into the virutalenv. I am on windows and I am using visual studio code.

Answer (score 1):

To open virtual env through command prompt,

run, `activate.bat`

```
\test\Scripts\activate.bat
```

for bash run,

```
source test/bin/activate
```

Comment: vs code has a cmd, terminal, etc. typing there is same thing, just make sure that if you choose cmd type the above and if you have chosen bash terminal type the below line part but make sure you reach activate/activate.bat either way. Typing in terminal window (cmd) will require you to give full path so i suggest type in vs code.

Answer (score 0):

just go to the left below corner where your python version is written click it, it will open the command palette where select the virtual env. (with its name) that's is test and press ok.
After that open new terminal and you will get what you want

Answer (score 0):

In cmd typing `test/Scripts/activate` worked, but in vscode terminal, I had to `cd` till the `Scripts` and then type `.\activate`.